# Unable to load Pop up using BootStrap

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I'm trying to show a pop-up when user clicks a button. Plz help me:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showChat="false"  showHeader="false">
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css')}" />
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css')}" />    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}" />    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css.map')}" />    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map')}" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Event Description</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
            Event Description Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Level Description</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
            Level Description Text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Ok but what happens ? Do you have any error ? What's going wrong ? Please provide more informations concerning your problem.

Comment: Nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: Did you try to replace `data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm"` by this : `data-target="#bs-example-modal-sm"` and with the modal like this : `<div id="bs-example-modal-sm" class="modal fade"` ?

Comment: Yes, i tried that. But it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't include Bootstrap Javascript and JQuery libraries. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Bootstrap Javascript` and `JQuery` librairies at the bottom on your file :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_total_file,'bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}" />
```

Comment: I have included them but didn't effect the interface.Below are the total files i have included:  
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_3_3_1,'bootstrap-3.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css')}" />    
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_3_3_1,'bootstrap-3.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />        
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_3_3_1,'bootstrap-3.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}" /> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You don"t have any JS errors ? And add the `//` at the start of  the URL : `<script src="//ajax.googleapis...`

Comment: I have changed it.still doesn't effect the things. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.1 version. Does it effects

Comment: I think it's ok. Did you try to run your code with a console opened like Firebug to see any JS errors ?

Comment: It is giving the error as follows: **bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery** but i have provided the jquery src file

Comment: Did you include the JQuery library before Bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes, i have intialized this script **    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>** before bootstrap

Comment: So you include in this order : bootstrap.min.css, jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js ?

Comment: Errors got increased when applied your sequence. But the main error is **Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery**

Comment: You just include this 3 librairies, in this order, and nothing other Bootstrap librairies ?

Comment: Yes,Done in the same order. Regarding errors, my apologize. i didn't refreshed the page so errors got increased. When i refresh the execution there is only one error as specified above. 
This the hierarchy i used:
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_3_3_1,'bootstrap-3.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}" />        
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap_3_3_1,'bootstrap-3.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>

Comment: Ok and if you try to include in this order : JQuery, CSS and JS ? I remember that order is important.

Comment: Thank You pal. It's working if i maintain the order:  JQuery, CSS and JS

Comment: Ok, good news ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery and the javascript bootstrap library. They are required to use the modal feature.